# How to refresh or load only user control which is placed on the asp.net web page?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have created the asp.net user control. And user control contains the asp.net button for data storing in the database. I have placed the user control on my aspx page. When i'm clicking on the button which is placed on the user control my whole page get loaded newly. But i want to load only content of the user control.

how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the user control inside a update panel.

Answer (score 0):

The post back is suppose to that , if you can't use update panel then you need to use some other async way to make a server side request on button click. I would suggest you go for jquery ajax calls.